# Does "Moe Moe Kyun" mean anything?

Tags: culture, disgaea

In *Disgaea 3 - Absence of Justice/Detention*, during the story scene of *Evil Academy Culture Fair* Map 2, when Salvitore, Master Big Star and Mao were looking for the one who was trying to destroy the Culture Fair, they arrived at the Sophomore's "Super Elegant Cafe".

When Master Big Star tried to point out that his Sophomores couldn't be the culprits, Mao got suspicious and said:

> Not to mention, all the food as cursed writing, chanting "Moe Moe Kyun♥" to cast spells, and confusing all your customers!

Given Evil Academy, with how the Cafe looked and how Master Big Star was willing to force Mr. Champloo to make bad food to satisfy some customers (which was against Mr. Champloo's ideals as the Home Ec Teacher), it seemed to be an act of delinquency (in Evil Academy, Delinquents did good thing like volunteer work and going to class, while Honor Students did the opposite - skipping class, breaking rules, etc.). Since Mao was an Honor Student, I assume "cursed writing" and "chanting" are normal things we would expect in a cafe (as Mao was suspicious of the Cafe from the beginning before they said "Welcome back students who are coming in for the first time")

I can assume "cursed writing" would be like notes written on the food like you do with cupcakes. However, while I know what Moe is supposed to be, I don't understand what "Moe Moe Kyun♥" is. Does this have anything to do with maid cafes or Japanese culture in general?

Comment: [Urban Dictionary to the rescue!](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Moe%20moe%2C%20kyun!)

Comment: @キルア so i can assume it's actually originated from K-On since normally if i expect a comment about something being "uber" cute i'd expect Kawaii (i don't play with japanese voices but i assume Sapphire would say kawaii when talking about her unresistible urge to smother Beryl with a hug)

Comment: Moe Moe Kyun Kyun is like abracadabra but restricted for Mahou Shoujo and Japanese Maids.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While of course the word "moe" is Japanese slang with a particular meaning that doesn't really translate to English, it's for a very specific type of cute, and the entire phrase is supposed to sound sort of like cutesy nonsense (which as far as I know, not really grammatical at least according to Japanese textbook).  However, *Moe moe kyun* has also become somewhat of a meme - a sound to indicate something is sooooo cute. Sort of like baby talk I guess. According to Urban Dictionary, [*Moe moe kyun* was used in the anime K-On!](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Moe+moe%2C+kyun!&defid=4756336)

I don't recall whether *Moe Moe Kyun* was literally used in the Japanese dialog for Disgaea 3 or not, but I *do* know that in general, the translators for the Disgaea series have been known to insert direct anime and video game references even when they weren't there in the original Japanese script. For example, in Disgaea 4, Fuuka yells "Objection!" in the English translation (reference to Phoenix Wright), but I'm pretty sure she did not say the equivalent in Japanese (「異議あり」　"Igiari!").  But, anyways, I would not be surprised if it were inserted in the English as an actual reference to K-On!, or perhaps it was even there in the Japanese as a K-On! reference.

Comment: "Moe moe kyun" was also the catch phrase in Hyakka Ryouran: Samurai Bride, when they turn the dojo into a maid cafe, probably also a reference to the "moe moe kyun" in K-ON.

Answer (score 2):

It means "abracadabra" essentially. It's a spell they recite in maid cafes when they serve food to customers in order to "make it taste better." Kind of like abracadabra, it doesn't really mean anything as a phrase or do anything physically to the food, but it signifies an incantation and is part of the ritual and attention giving aspects of maid cafes. 
-Source: worked in a maid cafe.